# IRepository and Related Data?

Tags: c#, .net, irepository

a couple of weeks ago i just got a test for a job interview, the thing is that i've resolved almost everything except one point, that at this point, i guess it's impossible to resolve. but for sure i'm wrong.

This problem deals with related data.  Our server API, IRepository, will only return a node with its immediate children (for example imagine that FakeRepository is loading from a Database.  You must not change the code in FakeRepository for this test).

Imagine that the NodeManager is client side code.

> We want to make sure that there is only ever one instance of a specific object on the client, so that  our client has a consistent view of data in our application. The test “LoadingNodeB_ShouldAlwaysReturnTheSameInstance()” demonstrates this problem.  Modify the code in the NodeManager so that this test passes.

so, we have this IRepo

```
namespace TestRecruitment.Repository
{
    public interface IRepository
    {
        Node GetNodeAndImmediateChildren(string nodeName);
    }
}
```

and in a test project we have a fakerepository that loads the information.

```
using System;

using TestRecruitment.Repository;

namespace TestRecruitment.Test.Repository
{
    public class FakeRepository : IRepository
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// YOU MUST NOT CHANGE THIS METHOD
        /// </summary>
        public Node GetNodeAndImmediateChildren(string nodeName)
        {
            switch (nodeName)
            {
                case "Node A":
                    // do not modify this
                    var nodeB = new Node { Name = "Node B" };
                    var nodeC = new Node { Name = "Node C" };
                    return new Node { Name = "Node A", ImmediateChildren = new[] { nodeB, nodeC } };
                case "Node B":
                    // do not modify this
                    var nodeD = new Node { Name = "Node D" };
                    var nodeE = new Node { Name = "Node E" };
                    return new Node { Name = "Node B", ImmediateChildren = new[] { nodeD, nodeE } };
                case "Node E":
                    var nodeA = new Node { Name = "Node A" };
                    var nodeF = new Node { Name = "Node F" };
                    return new Node { Name = "Node E", ImmediateChildren = new[] { nodeA, nodeF } };
                default:
                    throw new ApplicationException("Unknown node");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the thing is that you only can change the repository, you can't touch any other code.

```
using System.Linq;

namespace TestRecruitment.Repository
{
    public class NodeManager
    {
        private readonly IRepository _nodeRepository;

        public NodeManager(IRepository nodeRepository)
        {
            _nodeRepository = nodeRepository;
        }

        public Node GetNodeAndImmediateChildren(string name)
        {
            return _nodeRepository.GetNodeAndImmediateChildren(name);
        }
    }
}
```

well, that's it.

any help will be appreciated, i just want to know, how to resolve it.

i've created a github repo https://github.com/rothariger/TestRecruitment

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a node is uniquely identified by its name, one way of making sure you return the same instance is to keep a local cache in the client and maintain the `Node.ImmediateChildren` collection every time a call is made to the repository:

```
public class NodeManager
{
    private readonly IRepository _nodeRepository;

    private readonly Dictionary<string, Node> _cachedNodes = new Dictionary<string, Node>();

    public NodeManager(IRepository nodeRepository)
    {
        _nodeRepository = nodeRepository;
    }

    public Node GetNodeAndImmediateChildren(string name)
    {
        var repositoryNode =_nodeRepository.GetNodeAndImmediateChildren(name);
        UpdateCache(repositoryNode);
        return _cachedNodes[repositoryNode.Name];
    }

    private void UpdateCache(Node repositoryNode)
    {
        AddOrUpdateChildrenCollectionInCache(repositoryNode);

        foreach (var childNode in repositoryNode.ImmediateChildren)
        {
            AddOrUpdateChildrenCollectionInCache(childNode);
        }
    }

    private void AddOrUpdateChildrenCollectionInCache(Node repoNode)
    {
        if (_cachedNodes.TryGetValue(repoNode.Name, out var cachedNode))
        {
            cachedNode.ImmediateChildren = repoNode.ImmediateChildren;
        }
        else
        {
            _cachedNodes.Add(repoNode.Name, repoNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i didn't thinked to use a cache... although it could impact on performance, but we don't have that premise here... Thanks a lot!!!